# Tikz text not adjusting itself for the arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, automata

I have the code below which produces the image (unfortunately the code doesnt work since the image files are not available here). The text "Done" is for some reason getting placed well below the arrow. How can I fix that ?

```
\begin{flushleft}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto, node distance=8.5cm ,semithick]

 \node [draw=none, initial, initial text=\textbf{Initial Query},initial where=above](part1){\includegraphics[width=7.5cm,height=6cm,keepaspectratio=true]{byhalfpart1.jpg}};

    \node [draw=none](part2)[right of=part1] {\includegraphics[width=7.5cm,height=6cm,keepaspectratio=true]{byhalfpart2.jpg}
};

\path (part1) edge[]   node{} (part2);
    \coordinate[below of=part2] (d1);

\path (part2) edge[shorten >=5cm]  node{Done} (d1);

%    \draw [shorten >=5cm] (part2) to[] node[auto] {\textbf{Done}} (d1);
\end{tikzpicture}\\
\end{flushleft}
```

[image]

Comment: You use `shorten >=5cm` in the `path` towards the `node` with the `Done` label. Have you tried decreasing this value?

Comment: yes but then the arrow gets very long which I don't want =/

Comment: You have a node distance of 8.5cm.  That pushes the "dl" node down, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without a full **M** inimal **W** orking **E** xample, it was hard to find out what might be done. I thing you can use the notion `right=2cm of node.anchor` like in this small example:

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[textnode/.style={align=left},   -latex]

\node (iq) {initial query};
\node[textnode,below=1cm of iq.south] (part1) {part1 part1\\ part1 part1\\ part1 part1\\ part1 part1};
\node[textnode,right=1cm of part1.east] (part2) {part2 part2\\ part2 part2\\ part2 part2\\ part2 part2\\ part2 part2};
\node[below=1cm of part2.south] (d1) {Done};

\draw (iq) -- (part1);
\draw (part1) -- (part2);
\draw (part2) -- (d1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]